# Accessing properties of object using Spring bean in BIRT

Tags: spring, reporting, birt

I am trying to retrieve a value object by calling a method on a bean sitting in spring context by following the example at http://www.springsource.org/BusinessIntelligenceWithSpringAndBIRT

However this example shows that only the make of the car can be retrieved. Is there a way to retrieve the car object itself in birt context and than map individual properties of car to different elements in the data set or to use them to render the report.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but I found http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2009/11/more-on-birt-and-spring.html

Comment: After doing more analysis, it seems to me that there is no way to access the property in the way I was trying to do as mentioned in the question. Accessing each property results in more calls going back nad forth. The way I have done write now is to write the restful webservice and access it using XML datasource.